# Better lookup of variables

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a woocommerce details page. Mostly without much front-end woocommerce functions. On the details page I have (6) stores inventory potentially using this layout - one product displayed at a time.

There are certain details that have to be store specific, ie phone, location, and carfax id. I've stored the corresponding id/data in a custom plugin seen as the `"get_option"` below.

Obviously below code won't work - but its close to my goal:

```
$product=>attribute['dealer-location'] = 'x' echo options($q,$r,$s);
```

I feel the below code is horribly inefficient - and because of the use of headway I have to use this every time I have a new block and want to get the phone or review ID. Worried I'll add `~1-2seconds` on load waiting for all this to find replace(s) before page load.

```
<?php
global $product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
$dealerlookup = $attributes['dealer-location'];
$dealerlookupid = $dealerlookup['value'];

//if ($dealerlookup = 'acuraofspring')
//   $cat_id = get_option( 'aos-review-cat-id' );
//    if ($dealerlookup = 'jwacura') {
//        $cat_id = get_option( 'akc-review-cat-id' );
//    }
//    else {
//        $cat_id = '555';
//    }


$aosdealerid = get_option( 'aos-review-cat-id' );
$akcdealerid = get_option( 'akc-review-cat-id' );
$hkcdealerid = get_option( 'hkc-review-cat-id' );
$tkcdealerid = get_option( 'tkc-review-cat-id' );
$twcdealerid = get_option( 'twc-review-cat-id' );
$outdealerid = get_option( 'out-review-cat-id' );

$dealercommon = array ("acuraofspring","jwacura","jwautooutlet", "jwhonda", "jwtoyotawc", "jwtoyotakc");
$dealerreviewid = array ($aosdealerid,$akcdealerid, $outdealerid, $hkcdealerid, $twcdealerid, $tkcdealerid);

$cat_id = str_replace($dealercommon,$dealerreviewid,$dealerlookupid);

echo $cat_id;

$args=array(
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'post_type' => 'dealer-review',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
```